# asp GridView with embedded LinqDataSource/ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, gridview, user-controls, .net-datasourcecontrol

What i am trying to do is inherit a GridView and embed a LinqDataSource programatically into it. The reason for this is i want to have a generic grid view, that allows the markup definition of columns and grid properties but that implements a GetDataSourceEvent that will pass the sortExpression, pager page index, and pager row count for efficient model querying. The latter will be done by subscribing to the Selecting event of the DataSourceControl.

The problem i am encountering is that if i add the LinqDataSource to the UserControl the DataSourceId cannot be found. I tried the OnInit and the EnsureChildControls to create the LinqDataSource, but no luck. I've seen some examples of how we can create custom Pagers by inheriting the gridview, but i cant seem to find the appropriate events for my situation.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in trying to add a DataSourceControl programatically and assigning the GridView DataSourceId to it?

Comment: This is an asp.net question, it shouldn't be tagged as classic asp

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public method  that accepts your data source type.  Then, when you create an instance of your user control class, bind to the method.  For example, if you were using a list of string as your data source and had a user control called myUserControl:

```
Partial Class user_controls_myUserControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl


    Public Sub bindMyData(ByVal myDataSource As List(Of String))
      'bind stuff here
    End Sub

End Class
```

This would be called like this:

```
dim myListOfString as new list(of String)
Me.myUserControl1.bindMyData(myListOfString)
```

Comment: The whole point of the implementation is to make use of the events behind a DataSourceControl/ObjectDataSource/LinqDataSource, and to allow binding to a generic List<T> datasource. I want to be able to expose an event that can be handled to pass in the datasource. This event will be loaded with information regarding the number of rows to retrieve, the offset, sort order,etc. So patterns aside, i'm basically interested in how i can persist a dynamically created LinqDataSource.